# Check constraint on multiple columns for BETWEEN

Tags: mysql, multiple-columns, check-constraints

```
CREATE TABLE item( id int, number1 float, number2 float, number3 float, number 4 float, PRIMARY KEY(id), 
CONSTRAINT valid_numbers CHECK(
(number1 BETWEEN -1 and 1) AND
(number2 BETWEEN -1 and 1) AND
(number3 BETWEEN -1 and 1) AND
(number4 BETWEEN -1 and 1)
));
```

The columns number1, number2, number3, and number4 are all similar because they are floats that need to be between -1 and 1; however they're values are different.

How would I simply this statement? For example, if it went all the way up to number15. I don't want to say "`BETWEEN -1 and 1`" 15 times, I'd like to say it only once.

Comment: The only constraint that MySQL supports is foreign keys.

Comment: MySQL also enforces `NOT NULL` constraints, and some inherent "constraints" for each datatype (INT, DATE, ENUM, etc.)

Comment: I meant the only `CONSTRAINT` clauses that it obeys.

Comment: @Barmar: Confirmed; you are correct, as you always are.

Answer (score 0):

There's really no way to "simplify" this.

We could use an expression that avoids repeating `BETWEEN -1 AND 1` multiple times, but it really isn't any simpler.

For example:

```
 GREATEST(ABS(IFNULL(number1,0))
         ,ABS(IFNULL(number2,0))
         ,ABS(IFNULL(number3,0))
         ,ABS(IFNULL(number4,0))
         ) <= 1
```

If any of the values in `number1` through `number4` are less than -1 or greater than 1, the expression will return FALSE.

---

But, MySQL doesn't enforce `CHECK` constraints. If you want this type of constraint actually enforced, you'll need to put that logic into `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers.

> The `CHECK` clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html